# Discord.js embed command

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord, discord.js

**Some Info:**

I've been trying to make a command that makes the bot embed a title and description (ex. !embed (Title here) | (Description here)) so anyone who has the right permissions can use the bot to embed but I'm either really dumb or extremely persistent on a so called lead in my code that leads to nowhere.

**Problem:**

Cannot seem to get the title input and the description input to not mess with each other in a weird way (Putting the title into the description or the other way around) the vertical slash is suppose to be the divider between the title and description but I can't get it to work no-matter how hard I mess with my code.

**Code:**

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");

module.exports.run = async (client, msg, args) => {

    args.slice(0).join(" ")

    let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor("RANDOM")
    .setTitle(args[0])
    .setDescription(args.slice(1).join(" "))

    msg.channel.send(embed);
}

module.exports.help = {
    name: "embed"
}
```

Comment: Can you be a little more specific what you mean by "not mess with each other in a weird way" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is just here `args.slice(0).join(" ")`.

You need to store the new value of the args into the args value to update it.

So change that to: `args = args.slice(0).join(" ")`

And normally it will perfectly work!

**Edit:**

You can use a specific typo in the command like `-command -t Title with multiple words -d Description with multiple words`.
Then you can adapt your code.

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");

module.exports.run = async (client, msg, args) => {

    args.slice(0).join(" ")

    let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor("RANDOM")
    .setTitle(args.join(" ").split("-t")[1].split("-d")[0].trim())
    .setDescription(args.join(" ").split("-d")[1].trim())

    msg.channel.send(embed);
}

module.exports.help = {
    name: "embed"
}
```

Comment: I don't know how to make the title not appear in the desc or how to make the title longer than 1 word.

Comment: You helped me alot m8 thanks I've been stuck on this for a day and a half without sleep i can rest easy now. Good luck to your endeavors!

Comment: Thanks! Good luck on your development way ;)